# Yii CExtController and generatePath method

Tags: php, yii

I need to create extension what will work with some url (as I understood with [CExtController](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CExtController)).

So I created extension:

```
class MyExt extends CExtController{

    public $forceCopy = false;
    public $_published = array();

    public $layout = 'ext.MyExt.views.layouts.column2';

    public function actionIndex(){

        $models = $this->getModelList();

        $this->render('modelList', array('models' => $models));
    }
}
```

And layout file:

```
<?php 
$x = CAssetManager::publish(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../assets');
print_R($x);
die;
?>
```

But got Warning:

> MyExtand its behaviors do not have a method or closure named
>   "generatePath".

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is at this line `$x = CAssetManager::publish(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../assets');`. You are calling `publish()` method statically, but it is not static. Change it to

```
Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../assets');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this link ? 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.create

```
class MyExt CExtController
```

You have defined two classes at once. 
You can not say this. Maybe you mean

```
class MyExt extends CExtController
```

You have missing extends keyword

Comment: It just typo... I saw that link but didn't find anything about my problem.